# How minimize more equality constraints than independant variables in scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimize

I have this minimization problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, minimize, fmin_cobyla, linprog

A = \
np.array([[ 0.106667,  0.1333,  0.1333,  0.01],
          [ 0.02,  0.6667,  0.1333,  0.12],
          [0.0933,  0.06667,  0.6,  0.01]])

B = \
np.array([[27],
          [57],
          [28]])

l = \
np.array([[100],
          [40],
          [10],
          [50]])
u = \
np.array([[200],
          [80],
          [20],
          [150]])

def objfun(x):
    return abs(np.sum(x - (u+l)/2))

x0 = \
np.array([[150],
          [60],
          [15],
          [100]])

bounds = Bounds(l, u)

eq_cons1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.matmul(A[0,:],x)-B[0]}
eq_cons2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.matmul(A[1,:],x)-B[1]}
eq_cons3 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.matmul(A[2,:],x)-B[2]}
eq_cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x%1}
res = minimize(objfun, x0,  method='SLSQP',
               constraints=[eq_cons1, eq_cons2, eq_cons3, eq_cons],
               bounds=bounds)
```

but adding the last constraint

```
eq_cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x%1}
```

makes it fail

with the following error

More equality constraints than independent variables    (Exit mode 2)

How can we properly use scipy to solve this kind of problem.

I need for example x to be a multiple of a certain constant k. Thats why I'm using modulo.

Thanks

Comment: This should be formulated as a linear MIP problem.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen how can I linearize the objective function : np.sum((x - (u+l)/2)**2) ?

Comment: The obj was stated as: `abs(np.sum(x - (u+l)/2))` which is different from `np.sum((x - (u+l)/2)**2) `.  I was talking about the objective in the question.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to make it continuous by removing the abs first. But how do you linearize `abs(np.sum(x - (u+l)/2))` ? with Taylor? Because I'm gonna be far from the value of approximation.

Comment: This is very easy to linearize. Any textbook on Linear Programming will explain this. Also note that `sum(abs())` is not the same as `abs(sum())`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note that all your vectors B, l, u, x0 have
dimension 2 and should have dimension 1 instead. That's the same mistake
as in your last question. Using np.arrays with wrong dimensions for vectors
will lead to surprising results due to numpy's broadcasting, so please
try to keep an eye on your array dimensions.

Some notes in arbitrary order:

- Assuming your vectors have the right dimension, your first three constraints can be written as a single vectorial constraint
  function: `lambda x: A @ x - B`. Here, `@` denotes the matrix multiplication operator which calls np.matmul under the hood. This makes your code less verbose.
- Your initial guess `x0` is not feasible and violates your equality constraints.
- You should be aware that there are some things going wrong from a mathematical point of view. First, neither your objective nor your last constraint function is differentiable. Consequently, your optimization problem is not differentiable
  and violates the mathematical assumptions of the SLSQP algorithm. This can
  lead to really odd results in practice. You can easily make at least the objective
  differentiable by simply minimizing the square of the sum instead of the absolute value.
- Second, you have an optimization problem of four variables subject to
  seven equality constraints. Note that your modulo constraint is a vectorial
  constraint, i.e. it counts as four equality constraints. Hence, there's nothing
  to optimize since the solution to your problem (given that it exists) is
  already given by your constraints.
- Third and most importantly, your modulo constraint implies that your optimization variables should be integers, which turns your problem into a mixed-integer nonlinear optimization problem (MINLP) instead of a contiguous nonlinear optimization problem (NLP). However, scipy.optimize.minimize only supports the latter.

Long story short, you basically have two options:

1. Rewrite the problem as an integer optimization problem and solve it by a
   MINLP solver. Note also that your problem can also be formulated as a mixed-integer linear optimization problem (MILP) since the absolute value in your objective and the modulo constraint can be linearized.
2. You can replace the modulo function with a smooth approximation (e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491494/does-there-exist-a-smooth-approximation-of-x-bmod-y)) and solve
   the MINLP approximately by an NLP. Here, you could add a penalty term to the
   objective function that penalizes violations of the modulo constraint and thus tries to push the solution towards integral values. Afterwards, you can round the found solution to the nearest integral values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I linearize the objective function np.sum((x - (u+l)/2)**2) for example?